The passive and inanimate subjects and inroducting agents
It's often said that the passive in Japanese is unnatural with an inanimate subject because it's fundamentally about perception and affection. This seems to make sense on the surface but is also clearly wrong since “この番組は配信されている。” is evidently common use as well as the common “〜とされている” pattern freely being used with an inanimate subject as well as many other patterns.
However, I have noticed that passive sentences with an inanimate subject do not really seem to feature an agent introduced with “〜に” and in my recollection, they only seem to exist when the agent is essentially kept immaterial. So is it for instance still natural to say “この番組はあのテレビ局に配信されている。” or would something like “この番組はあのテレビ局が配信している。” be favored in that case? Can we say “盗撮は日本の社会に犯罪とされている。” and would it still be natural for instance?

It is called「無生物主語他動詞文」, and it is said that they are less common, but yes, there are many cases that they are used.
https://www.cajle.ca/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/Yamada_CAJLE2014_Proceedings_210-219.pdf
「この番組はあのテレビ局に配信されている。」: I feel this can be natural in some cases.「この番組はあのテレビ局が配信している。」This is more natural.
「盗撮は日本の社会に犯罪とされている。」I don't think even the active voice「日本の社会が盗撮を犯罪としている。」is natural. I would go with「盗撮は日本の社会で犯罪とされている。」.

I am also reading this one https://ls-japan.jpn.org/modules/documents/LSJpapers/meeting/155/papers/h/H-5_155.pdf and this one.
https://pragmatics.gr.jp/content/files/SIP_007/SIP_07_Machida.pdf
I must say this is a difficult problem.
